# Property returns different value than what was set

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on a Visual Studio extension and my current goal is to set up a menu item in the Tools menu. When clicked on this menu item will open a WinForms window containing a ListView, 3 textboxes, and a button. The idea is when you click on one of the rows in the ListView the data from that row will be populated in the textboxes so that you can update it. If you click the button a new row is added and the textboxes are cleared. However, I'm having an issue with getting the index of the row that I've selected.

```
private int _index;

private void newSourceBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Add new row to the ListView
    ListViewItem row = new ListViewItem();
    row.SubItems.Add("new");
    row.SubItems.Add(String.Empty);
    row.SubItems.Add(String.Empty);

    remoteSourceListView.Items.Add(row);
    int index = remoteSourceListView.Items.Count - 1;
    remoteSourceListView.Items[index].Selected = true;

    newSourceAdded = true;
    sourceNameTextBox.Clear();
    sourceUrlTextBox.Clear();
}

public void SourceName_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    remoteSourceListView.Items[IndexSelected].SubItems[1].Text = sourceNameTextBox.Text;
}

public void SourceURL_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string url = sourceUrlTextBox.Text;
    if ((url.StartsWith("http")) || (url.StartsWith("https")) || (url.StartsWith("git")))
    {
        sourceBranchTextBox.Enabled = true;
    }

    remoteSourceListView.Items[IndexSelected].SubItems[2].Text = url;
}

public void SourceBranch_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

public void SourcesListView_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ListView.SelectedListViewItemCollection selectedRows = remoteSourceListView.SelectedItems;

    foreach (ListViewItem row in selectedRows)
    {
        sourceNameTextBox.Text = row.SubItems[1].Text;
        sourceUrlTextBox.Text = row.SubItems[2].Text;

        IndexSelected = row.Index;

        if (row.SubItems[3].Text != "")
        {
            sourceBranchTextBox.Enabled = true;
            sourceBranchTextBox.Text = row.SubItems[3].Text;
        }
    }
}

public int IndexSelected
{
    get { return _index; }
    set { _index = value; }
}
```

This code shows the button click event which adds the new row to the ListView, the text changed events for each of the textboxes which updates the row in the ListView (sorta), and the selected index changed event for the ListView which is where I'm getting the index of the row that was just selected. While debugging, I noticed that when I click on a row I'm getting the correct index in the selected index changed event; however, when I call IndexSelected from either of the text changed events it is always giving me a different index.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the code posted I can't find any reason that explain the behavior documented.
A possible reason could be the insertion/deletion of new/existing ListViewItem in a position before the saved RowIndex.

However another approach is possible. Instead of keeping the RowIndex you could try to set a global property to the ListViewItem selected and reuse this instance when you need to set its subitems.

In this way you avoid problems if the number of ListViewItems change  and some item is inserted/removed before the saved RowIndex. However a safeguard against a null value should be provided.

```
private ListViewItem CurrentItemSelected {get;set;}
......

public void SourcesListView_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ListView.SelectedListViewItemCollection selectedRows = remoteSourceListView.SelectedItems;

    foreach (ListViewItem row in selectedRows)
    {
        sourceNameTextBox.Text = row.SubItems[1].Text;
        sourceUrlTextBox.Text = row.SubItems[2].Text;

        CurrentItemSelected = row;

        if (row.SubItems[3].Text != "")
        {
            sourceBranchTextBox.Enabled = true;
            sourceBranchTextBox.Text = row.SubItems[3].Text;
        }
    }
}

public void SourceName_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(CurrentItemSelected != null)
        CurrentItemSelected.SubItems[1].Text = sourceNameTextBox.Text;
}
```

However, I am a bit perplexed by your code. Do you have the property `MultiSelect` set to true? Because if it is set to false then your code doesn't need to loop.

```
public void SourcesListView_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(remoteSourceListView.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
    {
        // With MultiSelect = false; there is only one selected item.
        CurrentItemSelected = remoteSourceListView.SelectedItems[0];
        sourceNameTextBox.Text = CurrentItemSelected.SubItems[1].Text;
        sourceUrlTextBox.Text = CurrentItemSelected.SubItems[2].Text;
        if (CurrentItemSelected.SubItems[3].Text != "")
        {
            sourceBranchTextBox.Enabled = true;
            sourceBranchTextBox.Text = CurrentItemSelected.SubItems[3].Text;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, your solution worked perfectly!  I guess I was somehow adding the row before the saved RowIndex.